# Make an external File Usable for any app in Android 11 by adding to Media store

Tags: android, file, accessibility, mediastore, android-11

I have Created a sqlite db file this way :

```
public U_Bnt_DBSqlController openForLowerApi() throws SQLException {

        database  = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(fileBnt(), null);
         
        return this ;
    }
```

FilePath :

```
 public static File fileBnt() {
        File dir = null;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
           
            dir = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+ "/tilawaat"+"/"+"bnt.db" );
        } else {
            dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tilawaat"+"/"+"bnt.db");
        }

             if (!dir.exists())
            if(dir.mkdirs())
                Log.i(TAG, "fileBnt: Creating success");

        return dir;

    }
```

And it is created successfully. And I can read it. But after uninstall the app, I cant read the file again.

In Android [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#send-binary-content) Says :

The receiving application needs permission to access the data the Uri points to. The recommended ways to do this are:

Store the data in your own ContentProvider, making sure that other apps have the correct permission to access your provider. The preferred mechanism for providing access is to use per-URI permissions which are temporary and only grant access to the receiving application. An easy way to create a ContentProvider like this is to use the FileProvider helper class.
Use the system MediaStore. The MediaStore is primarily for video, audio and image MIME types, however beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11) it can also store non-media types (see MediaStore.Files for more info). Files can be inserted into the MediaStore using scanFile() after which a content:// style Uri suitable for sharing is passed to the provided onScanCompleted() callback. Note that once added to the system MediaStore the content is accessible to any app on the device.

My Question is How to Make Files Discoverable for another Any app (Including the App itself Which Makes the file ) ?  with regarding the line of the above documentation  `Note that once added to the system MediaStore the content is accessible to any app on the device.`

So, How could I  `added to the system MediaStore the content is accessible to any app on the device` ?

How to Add my files to System MediaStore that I can read it later ?

Or, More Specific, creating a file in Documents storage in Android 11, that the file can read any other app and the app itself even after the app itself uninstall and install it again ?

Comment: `fileBnt()` ??? What is that? And why didnt you tell full path of database file to begin with?

Comment: Database files are usually created in apps private storage and cannot be scanned by the media store. So media store is useless then.

Comment: @blackapps, sorry fileBnt(), is my externalPath, And I have created successfully the databse In Document directory, I can read and write in that file.

Comment: Please give full path of that directory. Of your externalPath. Be exact!

Comment: Please tell full path of your database file.

Comment: @blackapps, Thanks Brother,  I have edited my question with the full path, and I am working on Android 11 (R) .

Comment: You did not tell full path of that directory. Nor full path of your file. And you should handle mkdirs() as i told you at your other post.

Comment: Ok, though this is not the question, I have edited. So, Whats the answer you guess about the file can read  after unistall and intsall the app again ?

Comment: After about an hour you still did not tell full paths. And you messed around with mkdirs. Pretty reluctant.

Comment: can you not  see the method fileBnt() ? here is the full path. and without the mkdirs (I will manage that with getParentsDir), can know something about my real question ?

Comment: Yes. But not in the way you try to force me to.

Comment: Ok, I m not forcing you, this is the platform for seeking, not forcing, because, I described the path with editing the question, but without focusing my actual question, you only want the path,  if there is any wrong in my path, I cant able to open, write, edit, save, the db, again and again,   I guess.  My only question was, after uninstall the app I cant access any more. This behaviour not only for db file, even mp3 or any file. At least thanks for your response.